# RerfreshControl background does not cover

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to customize the refreshControl in my tableView. however when i pull down it seem to show a little white margin of the backgroundColor. Is there anyway beside changing backgroundColor to the same as refreshColor to avoid this? since by changing background Color it will be seen when i pull up and this won't be nice looking?

```
    reloadControl.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
    reloadControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    reloadControl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.tableView.addSubview(reloadControl)
```

[image]

Comment: Is that image in the cell below it all the way at the top of the cell? It might not be aligned correctly.